# How to check that user already saved address?

Tags: woocommerce

I searched woocommerce documents and I couldn't find any hook or function that checks: ***if user already has a saved address.***.

Is it totally possible to check? I will appreciate it if you give me documents or tips to check it.

The only solution that comes to my mind is using

```
if( has_bought() )
```

but it is not the best solution if users did not buy andy thing but they already saved an address on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by help of WooCommerce community. I share it here for other, who may need that:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$billing_address_1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1' );
if ($billing_address_1 ){
echo 'any text will be there.';
}
```